Compactness Theorem for propositional Calculus
The compactness Theorem of PC says that if for a possibility infinite Set of Propositional Formulas, Γ, has a Model (is Satisfiable) if and only if all its Finite Subsets have a Model (are Satisfiable).
I assume that we can understand a Model as a line in the possibly infinite Truth Table of the atomic proposition from which all the propositional formulas are built. That is, there is at list one line for which every formula of Γ is True.
My question is the following. Regarding the second side of the Iff. If we have a formula P, and two subsets Γ' and Γ'' respectively equal to {P} and {~P}, Γ' has a Model and Γ'' has a Model, but Γ' ∪ Γ'' has no model, because there is no line in which the Truth Value of P is both T and F, for both P and ~P being True together.
Therefore, since Γ is Γ' ∪ Γ'' ∪ Γ'' ∪..., Γ is not Satisfiable.
I don't understand this side of the Iff.
I would understand if the Theorem was be saying "if all of the subsets of Γ have at least a Common line for which their formulas are True, all the Formulas of Γ has are True. But the Theorem doesn't says this.
How can we explain it?

Perhaps contemplate why in point-set topology compactness implies completeness, while in foundational systems like PA propositional or first-order compactness doesn't imply completeness?...

I updated my answer to address the paragraph above "How can we explain it?"

@Annika there they write Iff

@kouty -- yes, I deleted it b/c the Swart book states it as if (p35) but others use iff

@kouty -- I updated my answer to hopefully addressed your concern -- the necessity of all subsets having a model is essentially stating there is a "line" in the (infinitely wide) truthtable where all formulas are true

@Annika Here the author wrote iff


I would understand if the Theorem was be saying "if all of the subsets of Γ have at least a Common line for which their formulas are True, all the Formulas of Γ has are True. But the Theorem doesn't says this.

That is exactly what it's saying -- but the concept of a "line" gets difficult if |Γ| = ∞ It's trivial for finite Γ

Note that if Γ is finite, the theorem is trivial, since Γ ⊆ Γ. So that leaves countably infinite set.

You're getting stuck in a similar way one gets stuck in Topology when considering compactness. The word every is very very important in the definition of the theorem.
You state that Γ', Γ''⊆Γ such that Γ'={P}, Γ''={¬P} both have models (namely Γ'[1], Γ''[0]).You then conclude that Γ must have a model. This is not correct.
Γ', Γ'' are two subsets of Γ -- the theorem requires every subset of Γ has a model. Well, Γ''' = Γ'∪ Γ'' is also a subset of Γ, but it is unsatisfiable and hence doesn't have a model.
Therefore, there is a subset of Γ that doesn't have a model, which prevents us from concluding that Γ has a model.
If the antecedent condition is true for the theorem, then we can use that to construct an inductive argument to cover all of Γ

So the right enunciation of the Theorem has to be: If all its finite subsets have a same model, then Gamma has a model. Right ?

No, the correct statement of the theorem is the one in the book, and in my answer, and in Annika's answer.

@kouty see Naim's comment. The book is fine. You are getting confused somewhere about what a model for a formula is. A model for one subset doesn't have to be the same model for another subset but EVERY finite subset must have a model (so not strictly the powerset of Γ due to the issue of infinite sets)

@Annika I mean that their formulas are true for some same line in the Truth Table

@kouty that is the mistake -- it's just saying there is some line in the truth table that makes each subset true, but they could be different interpretations of the entire set of formulas

@Annika a model is not necessary only one line?

@kouty — no if Γ is a set of tautologies then every row is a model

@Annika I mean almost one line of course

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

The compactness theorem says that a set Γ of first-order sentences has a model if and only if every finite subset (not necessarily proper!) of Γ has a model. In your case, the subset {P, ¬P} ⊆ {P, ¬P} has no model, so there is no contradiction. In general, the compactness theorem doesn't say anything interesting for finite sets of formulas.

But {P} has a model, and {~P} too, so we must say that no more than one of them can be a subset of Gamma?

I don't understand the question. The conclusion of the compactness theorem is false, as you observed; this isn't a problem because its premise is also false, as I showed (again: all the finite subsets of Γ are required to have a model, including Γ itself). What more do you want? That {Γ} and {¬Γ} happen to have models plays no role here.

see there p. 35 the proof of the Theorem, the words about a subset for which i(Pi) = 0, and afterwards the statement beginning with "then..." i (Pi) = 1.

@kouty -- I had this exact same book open when I was writing my answer. TBH - its not the easiest book to understand :-\

@Annika lol. He says that for Gamma ' I(P1) = 0,  and he concludes that we define i(P1) = 1, so Gamma ' has a model. Perhaps is he reasoning ab absurdum ? He's so saying that it's impossible for Gamma ' to be a subset of Gamma, but we still don't know if Gamma has a model. We are building it on the basis of union of modelized finite sets.

@NaïmFavier all the finite subsets of Γ are required to have a model, including Γ itself so you are proving that if Γ has a model, so Γ has a model?

I am not proving anything, but that's what the compactness theorem says for finite sets, yes. That's why I said it's not interesting for finite sets.
